# What is the best way to achieve buffered read from pipe in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, select, pipe, buffer

I am monitoring the read end of a pipe in a `select` loop and reading from it with `read` when data is available. I am always expecting a certain data format through the pipe which (for the sake of the example) is of type `struct packet_t`. My initial code performed the following operations on the file descriptor once the `select` call signaled it:

```
int
read_packet(int fd)
{
    struct packet_t pkt;

    int read_bytes = read(fd, &pkt, sizeof(pkt));
    if (bytes_read <= 0)
    {
        /* handle some sort of error */
        return -E_SOCK;
    }
    else if (bytes_read < sizeof(pkt))
    {
        /* return bad message format */
        return -E_BADMSG;
    }

    /* do something with the packet */
    return E_OK;
}
```

Obvisouly, the above fails to do what I intended because it may be the case that a `read` call will return less bytes than `sizeof(pkt)` just because of some delays and later, the rest of the bytes will be delivered as well, completing the packet. However, my code assumes that if a complete packet is not received in the first call to `read` than it must be a transmission error and all subsequent packets will be discarded as bad.

To fix this, I need to buffer the read, i.e. to read into a separate buffer and only interpret the buffer contents as a packet if the number of received bytes is at least `sizeof(pkt)`.

My quesions is: **is there a c++ class or technique to achieve buffered read nicely?** For example, I can construct a class `mybuffer` which holds the bytes already read and when it hits a threshold it calls a callback allowing me to read the packet. However, I don't want to reinvent the wheel if there is any wheel out there and I am asking whether there is a solution either in the standard library (for example using `iostream` or in other c++ libraries like `boost`.

Thank you for your support!